# Add results from two different queries together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using two different queries to get data. here I have joined using `union`.

```
SELECT
  IPOD.StockCode
 ,SUM(IPOD.OrderQty) / 12 AS newAverage
FROM
  InvPurchaseOrderHeader AS IPOH
  INNER JOIN
    InvPurchaseOrderDetail AS IPOD
      ON
      IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID
WHERE
  IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1
  AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY
  IPOD.StockCode
UNION
SELECT
  IPOD.StockCode
 ,SUM(IPOD.OrderQty) / 6 AS newAverage
FROM
  InvPurchaseOrderHeader AS IPOH
  INNER JOIN
    InvPurchaseOrderDetail AS IPOD
      ON
      IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID
WHERE
  IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1
  AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY
  IPOD.StockCode;
```

but the query above needs to sum up similar records 
currently it gives results like this.

```
4846000001-M    20.000000
4846000001-M    40.000000
4846000001-S    10.000000
4846000001-S    20.000000
```

but I need a data set like this

```
4846000001-M    60.000000
4846000001-S    30.000000
```

Furthermore I need to divide each resulting row value by 3

Final data set should look like this.

```
4846000001-M    20.000000
4846000001-S    10.000000
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two queries.  You can get the separate columns as:

```
select IPOD.StockCode,
       sum(case when IPOH.DocumentDate >= dateadd(month, -12, getdate()) then IPOD.OrderQty end)/12 as newAverage_12, 
       sum(case when IPOH.DocumentDate >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) then IPOD.OrderQty end)/6 as newAverage_6    
from InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH inner join
     InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD
     on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 
where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 
group by IPOD.StockCode;
```

You can readily add these together and divide by 3.

EDIT:

So, the answer to your specific question is:

```
select IPOD.StockCode,
       (sum(case when IPOH.DocumentDate >= dateadd(month, -12, getdate()) then IPOD.OrderQty end)/12 + 
        sum(case when IPOH.DocumentDate >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) then IPOD.OrderQty end)/6
       ) / 3
from InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH inner join
     InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD
     on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 
where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 
group by IPOD.StockCode;
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain how to add newAverage_12 to newAverage_6 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can just uses `sum()` function by using sub-query but condition aggregation is better that answered by sir @gordon

```
 select  t.StockCode,sum(newAverage)/3   from
(
select IPOD.StockCode, SUM(IPOD.OrderQty)/12 as newAverage from 

    InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH 
    INNER JOIN InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 

    where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY IPOD.StockCode

    union 

    select IPOD.StockCode, SUM(IPOD.OrderQty)/6 as newAverage from 

    InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH 
    INNER JOIN InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 

    where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY IPOD.StockCode)

) as t group by t.StockCode
```

Answer (score 0):

we can also use **avg()** function in this

```
select  t.StockCode,avg(newAverage)   from
(
select IPOD.StockCode as stockcode, SUM(IPOD.OrderQty)/12 as newAverage from 

    InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH 
    INNER JOIN InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 

    where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY IPOD.StockCode

    union 

    select IPOD.StockCode as stockcode, SUM(IPOD.OrderQty)/6 as newAverage from 

    InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH 
    INNER JOIN InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 

    where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY IPOD.StockCode)

) as t group by t.StockCode
```

you can also use **with** Clause

```
with data as
(
select IPOD.StockCode as stockcode, SUM(IPOD.OrderQty)/12 as newAverage from 

    InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH 
    INNER JOIN InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 

    where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY IPOD.StockCode

    union 

    select IPOD.StockCode as stockcode, SUM(IPOD.OrderQty)/6 as newAverage from 

    InvPurchaseOrderHeader IPOH 
    INNER JOIN InvPurchaseOrderDetail IPOD on IPOH.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID = IPOD.InvPurchaseOrderHeaderID 

    where IPOH.DocumentStatus = 1 AND IPOH.DocumentDate >= (DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY IPOD.StockCode)

),select stockcode,avg(newAverage) from data group by stockcode;
```